# Loop over multiple addresses: ping and drop data into file

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ping

I would like to be able to have a script that will:

1. look at a list of IP addresses
2. Ping one of the addresses
3. Take the data and drop it in to a file
4. Move on to the next IP

So far I have:

```
cd /Path/to/addressees || exit 1
for targethost in a b c; do
  {ping {targethost}
      echo $'\n'"finished:
  } >"$log_file" 2>&1
done
```

When I run this I receive the errors:

```
./ping_address: line 3: cd: /path/to/ip_adress: No such file or directory
./ping_address: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./ping_address: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I am still a little new to scripting on Unix so any help would be really helpful!

Comment: Your code does not match the error message... "/Path/to/addressees" vs. "/path/to/ip_adress"

Answer (score 3):

Several things:

1. You cannot cd to a file (you could use the `-f` test to see if the file exists - see below.)
2. I'm not sure of your use of 'a b c' - those are variables that should contain addresses?  It's unclear if your addresses are embedded into the script, or stored in a file.
3. Generally, you'll need a $ to reference a variable (i.e., `${targethost}` not `targethost`)  Omit the `$` when assigning.

Why not something like this (assuming you have a file called ip_addresses with a single address per line, or space separated addresses.)

```
#!/bin/bash
IP_FILE="/tmp/ip_address_file" # The file with the IP addresses
LOGFILE="/tmp/log_results"  # Where the results will be stored
if [[ ! -f ${IP_FILE} ]]; then
   echo "No File!"
   exit 1
fi
for IP_ADDRESS in $(cat $IP_FILE); do
   echo "TEST FOR ${IP_ADDRESS}" >> $LOGFILE
   # The -c 1 means send one packet, and the -t 1 means a 1 second timeout    
   ping -c 1 -t 1 ${IP_ADDRESS} >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 
done
```

Alternately, if you wanted to create a file for each IP you could use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP_FILE="/tmp/ip_address_file" # The file with the IP addresses
if [[ ! -f ${IP_FILE} ]]; then
   echo "No File!"
   exit 1
fi
for IP_ADDRESS in $(cat $IP_FILE); do
   echo "TEST FOR ${IP_ADDRESS}"
   # The -c 1 means send one packet, and the -t 1 means a 1 second timeout    
   ping -c 1 -t 1 ${IP_ADDRESS} >> ${IP_ADDRESS}.log 2>&1 
done
```

If you wanted to embed the IPs in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IPS='1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 4.4.4.4 5.5.5.5'
if [[ ! -f ${IP_FILE} ]]; then
   echo "No File!"
   exit 1
fi
for IP_ADDRESS in ${IPS}; do
   echo "TEST FOR ${IP_ADDRESS}"
   # The -c 1 means send one packet, and the -t 1 means a 1 second timeout    
   ping -c 1 -t 1 ${IP_ADDRESS} >> ${IP_ADDRESS}.log 2>&1 
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions!! I have one question, on the first script that user407001 posted. I got the script work but it isn't moving on to the next address in the IP_ADDRESS_file. it just gives me data from the first connection. TEST FOR (IP_ADDRESS)
ICMP Time exceeded in transit from (IP_ADDRESS)
 for icmp from (SERVERNAME) (IP_ADDRESS) to (IP_ADDRESS)

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted what you have (that isn't working.)  It sounds like perhaps you are re-opening the file each time through the loop somehow, so it gets "stuck" on the first line.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't get more obvious than that:

1. The directory `/path/to/ip_adress` has to be created before you run the script.
2. `"finished:` is missing a " at the end
3. The third error is just a consequence of the second.